# В каком формате сохранять изображения для xCode?

Tags: xcode, swift, изображения, графика, illustrator

Делаю арты к приложению в Adobe Illustrator, сохраняю в PNG (500х500 px).
Импортирую картинку в каталог Assets и применяю к ImageView, а в итоге на выходе получаю примерно такое качество. 
Пробовал покрутить настройки в инспекторе, но безрезультатно.

Не подскажите в каких форматах сохранять, что бы улучшить качество в приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сейчас сохраняем в pdf, а Xcode во время компиляции сам рендерит нужные png с альфой. Притом размер pdf должен быть равен размеру UIImageView в пойнтах. То есть у вас есть UIImageView 150х150 points, по идее вам нужно для каталога три размера .png - @1 (150х150pxl), @2(300x300pxl) и @3(450x450pxl). 
Вместо этого вы добавляете один pdf 150х150, и в инспекторе картинки выбираете Scales -> Single Scale, Devices -> Universal. Ну и если хотите программно красить: Render as -> Template Image.